# SEDE Migration failure (again)

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Another heads up placeholder for a broken migration this week.

Last week the migration failed for a few days due to problems encountered with the move to Denver.

Assuming Sunday morning UTC is still the time that migration is supposed to happen, this week's migration is overdue by more than half a day.

Comment: Cross site duplicate [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264457/158100)

Comment: Any chance you could synonymize those two tags?

Comment: @Deduplicator I just re/de tagged the questions tagged as "sede", there were only like 3 of em.

Comment: @CRABOLO: Considering everybody always talks about SEDE, I would like the synonym anyway.